# Installing electric on 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have a application developed in electric under Ubuntu 11.10, since then I had to do a fresh start and I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte but I have recently need to re-use the application I wrote but it won't compile under fuerte.

This is my fault as I used the version of pcl which came with electric out of lazyness, thus the majority of the problems.

As I am in a bit of a problem time-wise I will go back to electric, the problem being that even though the [electric page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu) there is no "add a source list" for Ubuntu 12.04 if one exists and someone knows it, or other solutions to apt-get electric, could you please post it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36980/installing-electric-on-12.04/) by [George Paul](https://answers.ros.org/users/2677/george-paul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [George Paul](https://answers.ros.org/users/2677/george-paul/) on 2012-06-21**:
Thanks I was afraid of this, I'll go back to 11.10 I really need the code fast for a presentation I'll upgrade it properly later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By [REP 3 - Target Platforms](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) there is no ROS electric pre-built for Ubuntu 12.04. You will have to either use a machine with Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric), upgrade your code to Fuerte, or build ROS electric from source.

Since electric was released in 2011, it couldn't possibly be compatible to Ubuntu 12.04 in advance.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find my notes on installing Electric on 12.04 from source here: http://answers.ros.org/question/37981/electric-running-under-ubuntu-1204-precise/#40063
I hope it's helpful.

---

Originally posted by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) with karma: 399 on 2012-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1